# Attempt to signing up for meta sites via Google or Facebook leads to a 404 page

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, 404-not-found, sign-up

In browser private mode opening any meta site (in case of existing the main site) allows you to sign up. For instance [SO.meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/):

> [image: SO.meta]

On the following page you can choose Google or Facebook as an external account to proceed with signing up.

> [image: Goobook]

But doing this leads to a 404 page:

> [image: 404]

Comment: While the sign up in top right corner-> google account works.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Because the sign up button at the top redirects you to the main site, like the banner button is supposed to. -- We don't support signing up directly on the meta site, so there are two separate issues here: 1) I don't think this particular banner is supposed to appear on meta sites at all. 2) The signup page on meta should redirect to the main site when visited.